# Correct order of overrides for a composite control based on an abstract one

Tags: c#, composite-controls

I'm writing a set of C# composite web server controls for displaying dialog boxes.

I want to have one abstract class which handles the basic layout and things like titles of the control, then have a set of derived ones which render child controls at a specific point.

I forsee three distincts methods: `renderOpeningHtml` handled by the abstract class, `renderCustomControls` as done by the derived class, and `renderClosingHtml` by the abstract class again, except I can't figure the life cycle of a CompositeControl and what methods to use when.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, figured it.

Used `public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)` and `RenderEndTag` for the abstract control, and `RenderContents` for the derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to do your own HTML rendering you could also consider deriving from `UserControl` and just adding to your `Controls` collection. The word "composite" seems to point in that direction.

Comment: Yeah, I'm put a bit of html in there.